# Set the last heading in a table to auto size to the button in the row

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" target="_blank" role="button">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Right now each heading takes up 25% of the table. Since the last heading is small and only contains a button in each row, I wanted to let the table autosize to the button or heading text. I could use a set `width` size but is it better to use another method?

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout: fixed;` property to the table.
To know more about it visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

Comment: You saved the day